# Simple VBA Rename Sheet, Copy information and transpose not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a simple VBA

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Download"
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Download").Range("A1:A2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")
    Range("A3:BB150").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:BB150").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, transpose:=True
```

When running the code renames Sheet1 to Download, adds a new sheet and the copies A1:A2 to the new sheet. However it will not copy and paste/transpose the data range with error 1004 (you can't paste here because the copy area and paste area aren't the same size, select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size and try pasting again).

When I only run:

```
Sheets("Download").Range("A1:A2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")
    Range("A3:BB150").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:BB150").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, transpose:=True
```

when on the "Download" sheet it works perfect, but if I run it on another sheet it fails. I'm not sure what the problem is here. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial`

Comment: Exact same error occurs

Comment: Are there any merged cells in the area you're copy/pasting?

Comment: Probably not causing the issue you're raising, but worth mentioning: you qualify almost all your ranges with a sheet name, except `Range("A3:BB150").Copy` which could cause some issues.

Comment: That was the problem thank you Ben. I tried to define it the line before using 
    `Sheets("Sheet1").Select` but that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry thank you CLR for the fix my apologies.